# Some mySQL statements only work after appending \g, other statements don't mind?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to embrace mySQL commands in the raw form without using phpMyAdmin and I ran into this little issue so far...

I'm just wondering, I can connect to my db using wamp server and some commands won't work without typing \g after. For instance, I can connect, type my password and then immediately if I just try to create a database via:

```
CREATE DATABASE testing
```

It pushes me into a newline that looks like so:

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE testing
    ->
```

1. How do I get back to a regular line to type after this happens? I keep having to close the command prompt and re initiate which is a hassle. 2. Why does it do this? Then when I type the following the command works just fine.

```
CREATE DATABASE testing \g
```

OK, now if that were the case I'd just understand and always type \g after everything because I know some things just "ARE" in programming. But then, I can type this line without the \g and it changes databases just fine.

```
USE firstdb
```

I haven't tested further on which commands do and don't work with/without the GO command but I thought I'd ask before I confuse myself a million times.

Much appreciated SO community! Thx in advance.

(Also, since I'm new to SO can someone please leave a comment on how to create those code snippets, but in the inline-block format so I don't have to always have to break my code references out onto new lines? Thanks!)

Comment: You need to end statements with `;`

Comment: All MySQL commands need the delimiter. Use, quit, help, etc. are the exception to the rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semicolon `;` is the standard statement delimiter in SQL.  In the case of MySQL, the server doesn't need to see it, so the command line client doesn't actually send it... but it waits for it, and nothing is sent to the server until a delimiter followed by a newline is encountered.

Exceptions are things that don't get sent to the server, or don't get sent as SQL.  (There's another way, other than the `USE` statement, to change the current database, using a specially-crafted packet, and afaik the MySQL cli still uses that method, which is, I assume, why `USE` is a strange exception.)

You can change the delimiter to something else.  Commonly, you'll see something like this

```
mysql>  DELIMITER $$
```

This allows you to send SQL to the server that contains a `;` en bloc, without the client thinking you were done when it saw what looks like a delimiter.  This is used for declaring procedures, functions, triggers, and events.  At the end of the statement, or group of statements, each terminated with `$$`, you set it back.

```
mysql> DELIMITER ;
```

Note there's a space before the `;`.