# mysql stored function syntax for dummies

Tags: mysql

I am appear to be having a bad case of brain flatulence at the moment. Can someone see the bleedingly obvious error in the following mysql stored function?

```
delimiter $$

drop function if exists test$$ 

create function test() 
returns boolean
begin
    return true;
end$$
```

I know it is dancing around the place, laughing its head off and waving its bare buttocks in my direction  - but I just cant see it.

The original error was in a much larger hunk of code that I have cut down to the above - but I can't seem to remove much more without running out of code to remove.
mysql version 5.7.14

Answer (score 2):

Drop the function before setting the new delimiter

```
DROP function IF EXISTS `test`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `A_DB`$$
CREATE FUNCTION `test` ()
RETURNS BOOLEAN
BEGIN
    RETURN TRUE;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I tried your version in this https://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/ and its falling over with a "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$
USE `A_DB`$$
CREATE FUNCTION `test` ()
RETURNS BOOLEAN
BEGIN
    RE' at line 3"

Comment: I managed to get this version past the mysql command line on my machine - still failing when loaded from file though.  The issue seems to be the final delimiter in fact.  Repeated runs of buggy code was leaving the delimiter in the the $$ state causing the next run of code to fail (at least when using the command line).

Comment: Try another delimiter, `$$` may be getting PHP confused if used in a double quoted string

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who comes this way again the problem turned out not to be with the SQL.  The issue was with the driver and my understanding of how mysql hangs together.

The delimiter statement is part of the MySQL client (command line) and is not part of any driver (or at least any on node i can find)

So if you are loading your sql by sucking in a string and squirting it at the database via a driver (nodejs mariasql in my case) then delimiter is not understood.

You either have to parse the delimiters out yourself - or be more elaborate and logon to the mysql client shell somehow and load the file.  I will probably simply put a line such as %start  sql stuff here %end and parse the sql into chunks - and squirt these at the driver.

Comment: Yes, `DELIMITER` is a client side *parser* directive used by the `mysql` command line interface (CLI) and emulated by othet clients.  The standard delimiter `;` at the end of a SQL query is accepted if sent with the query but not actually needed by the server.  The client keeps reading from the input until it sees that `;` and then sends the entire query *en bloc* to the server for execution.  Complex statements with `BEGIN`/`END` include embedded `;`, so that would never work unless there was a way to change the watched-for `;` to something else.  `DELIMITER` changes what the CLI looks for.

Comment: Also mentioned for context in an answer to different question, at http://stackoverflow.com/a/30066977/1695906.

Comment: Also note, this wouldn't properly be a function of the "driver."  It's a function of the thing that's using the driver -- your code -- because the driver executes statements, while your code is the entity that decides exactly what, from the available context, actually constitutes a single SQL statement.

Comment: I ended up doing just that.  Used my own delimiters in a file - load the file - split into strings on delimiters - remove control characters - trim trailing and leading whitespace and squirt it at the driver.